# How do I properly mask values in my Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm creating an encoder-decoder CNN for some images. Each image has a geometric shape around the center - circle, ellipse, etc.

I want my CNN to ignore all the values that are in this shape. All my input data values have been normalized to be around 0-1. I set all the shape values to be 0.

I thought that setting them to zero would mean that they will not be updated, however, the output of my encoder-decoder CNN changes the shape.

What can I do to ensure these values stay put and do not update?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore" the values? And by encoder-decoder, do you mean an autoencoder? As in, are you trying to reconstruct the image after pushing it through a bottlenecked latent space?

Comment: I want the geometry to stay fixed. I'm reconstructing a future time step of a flow past different shapes. Thus, I want the autoencoder to just learn the features around the shape.

Comment: I want the output to have the shape in the same place, untouched. Unlike an autoencoder that re-creates the input, this autoencoder is creating a different time step of the input. so, the data around the shape should change, not the actual shape.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for ["partial convolution"](https://github.com/NVIDIA/partialconv). This is a work published by Guilin Liu and colleagues that extends convolution to take an input mask as well as an input feature map and apply the convolution only to the unmasked pixels. They also suggest how to compensate for pixels on the boundary of the mask, where the kernel "sees" both valid and masked-out pixels.

Please note that their implementation may have issues running with automatic mixed precision (AMP).

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm having some trouble understanding how this works. Do I pass in another channel in my input data, of only the pixels I would like to mask? and then use 'PartialConv2d'? How do I specify the masked channel?